# How to move resources between projects in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have some API keys that I need to move between two projects in the same organization (for billing reasons and I also would like to avoid having to recreate these API keys because that will be a major headache with our apps). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Keys are Google Cloud project specific. They cannot be moved to a different project.